# Making an activity resizable

Tags: android, android-activity

I have this activity with a Constraint Layout:

[image: Activity]

And here is the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
        android:layout_width="383dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="1200"
        android:progress="0"
        android:scrollbarSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:tickMark="@color/colorAccent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="197dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="231dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/slider" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/comisionText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="142dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_effect"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/submitBtn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.678" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
        android:layout_width="181dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_effect"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/but" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/but"
        android:layout_width="217dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/total" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem is that when i try it on a smaller screen phone, it cuts off some of the objects from the bottom of the activity. How can i make it resizable so it can fit any screen size? Every object is constrained Top-To-Bottom of the object above it.

Comment: Are you sure that small phones have enough space to display your layout? May be you need to wrap your ConstraintLayout in ScrollView?

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to happen with this layout.  You should almost never be giving exact layout heights/widths if you want it to be resizable, you do it everywhere.  I don't think you actually understand how to write a layout for Android.  Anyplace you specify an exact size in Android is a sign of a likely mistake

Comment: I'm new to Android Studio, still learning this stuff. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ScrollView, so the user can scroll down and see the whole activity. Just wrapping your ConstraintLayout in ScrollView should be enough, like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".Activity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
            android:layout_width="383dp"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="1200"
            android:progress="0"
            android:scrollbarSize="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:tickMark="@color/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="197dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text"
            android:layout_width="231dp"
            android:layout_height="67dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/slider" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="94dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="142dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_effect"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/submitBtn"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.678" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
            android:layout_width="181dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_effect"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/but" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/but"
            android:layout_width="217dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/total"
            android:importantForAutofill="no" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Anyways, you should use `wrap_content` and `match_parent` instead of hard-coded sizes. Your layout needs to be flexible and adapt to different screen sizes, and that's not possible if you're using determined sizes in your layout. Please take a look into [Android Developer: Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

Comment: Thanks, that's a possible solution, but i don't really want to have to scroll down to the bottom. Would really like to have it resizable, if that is even possible.

Comment: It's not possible if you're using hard-coded sizes like  `android:layout_width="290dp"`
You should use `wrap_content` and `match_parent` instead. I edited my answer to add some more information. You're essentially using "dp" which is "density-independent pixel", which ensures that the elements will appear the same size on different screens

Comment: Thank you very much, i understand now.